# How to get properties from json API when using fetch, cors?

Tags: javascript, json, api, asynchronous, fetch-api

I need to get properties by accessing this link.

```
        fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/28/").then(results => {
           console.log(results);
        })
```

I receive this respond in console.

> Response {type: "cors", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/28/",
>   redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} body:(...) bodyUsed:true
>   headers:Headers {} ok:true redirected:false status:200 statusText:""
>   type:"cors" url:"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/28/"
>   **proto**:Response

But I expect to see something like this:

> 

```
            {   "forms": [      {           "url":
            > "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/28/",             "name": "sandslash"
            >       }   ],  "abilities": [      {           "slot": 3,          "is_hidden": true,
            >           "ability": {
            >               "url":  "name": "defense"   

                 ...
```

And so on...how can I get this data?
            I can access it from their website pokeapi.co, but not from my app.
            What I am doing wrong? Please, help me to understand!!

Answer (score 1):

```
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/28/").then(results => { return results.json();
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

This is a solution. It's strange, because few hours ago it was a different response.